# Why the object wrapper for an int is Integer and not Int?

Tags: java

I've seen that whe have the following mapping between primitive and object version of a variabile:

- float -> **F**loat
- double -> **D**ouble
- boolean -> **B**oolean
- byte -> **B**yte
- short -> **S**hort
- ...

So, for all of them the only difference is the first letter of the world. I would like to know why this rule does not apply for *int* that becomes **Integer** (and not **I**nt) and for *char* that becomes **Character** and not (**C**har).

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but I would really like to know if there is a reason for this choice, even because I teach java to kids and often they ask the same question to me.

Comment: It matters to me, I know, it's not a pure technical question but I would like to know if there is a reason for this choice and, IMHO stack overflow is a good place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because JDK classes honor the Java naming convention.

> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. (...) Use whole words-***avoid acronyms and abbreviations*** (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).

Reference:

[Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)